# Using jackson xml mapper to map java list in xml

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson, mapper

I've a problem with xml Mapper.
I'm using the com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper library.
Practically, this is my java bean that map the values in this way:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName ="Patient")
public class Patient implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2981849269841429849L;
  @JsonProperty("patientId")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String patientId;
  @JsonProperty("patientName")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String patientName;
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Series")
  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
  private ArrayList<Serie> listSerie;
}
```

and generate in the main class the xml with:

```
Wado mapp = new Wado();
mapp.setvalue("bla bla");
String xmlWado = new XmlMapper().writeValueAsString(wado);
```

the result is:

```
<Patient patientId="" patientName="">
<Series>
<Series></Series>
<Series></Series>
<Series></Series>
</Series>
```

that's not I was expected. I want:

```
<Patient patientId="" patientName="">
<Series></Series>
<Series></Series>
<Series></Series>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Copying your code and faking out the classes that you didn't post, I can't reproduce your problem. I get your expected result + the closing tag you forgot. What version of jackson are you using?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've resolved problem using the library org.codehaus.jackson and add the dependency:
-com.fasterxml 
-com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat
-org.codehaus.woodstox